# npm start (angular 11) throws an error (Unknown error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*')

Tags: angular, npm-start

I am getting this error frequently, if I removed the project then download it again then it's work, but after restarting my pc the same error occurred again.

My global angular version and project angular versions are the same.

**If I delete the node modules and reinstall the packages it works, but every time doing this is really a wastage of time.**

Error message snippet:
[image: Error message and angular version]

Corresponding error logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle e-commerce-admin@0.0.0~prestart: e-commerce-admin@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle e-commerce-admin@0.0.0~start: e-commerce-admin@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle e-commerce-admin@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle e-commerce-admin@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\e-commerce-admin\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\inval\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\inval\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\inval\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle e-commerce-admin@0.0.0~start: CWD: D:\e-commerce-admin
10 silly lifecycle e-commerce-admin@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng serve' ]
11 info lifecycle e-commerce-admin@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 verbose stack Error: e-commerce-admin@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
13 verbose pkgid e-commerce-admin@0.0.0
14 verbose cwd D:\e-commerce-admin
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
17 verbose node v14.16.0
18 verbose npm  v6.14.11
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error syscall spawn
21 error file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error e-commerce-admin@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the e-commerce-admin@0.0.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json

```
{
"name": "e-commerce-admin",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
 "ng": "ng",
 "start": "ng serve",
 "build": "ng build",
 "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
 "test": "ng test",
 "lint": "ng lint",
 "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^11.1.0",
 "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.0",
 "@angular/common": "^11.1.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.0",
 "@angular/core": "^11.1.0",
 "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
 "@angular/forms": "^11.1.0",
 "@angular/material": "^11.1.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.0",
 "@angular/router": "~11.1.0",
 "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.1.0",
 "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
 "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
 "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
 "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
 "tslib": "^2.1.0",
 "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.4",
 "@angular/cli": "~11.1.0",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.0",
 "@angular/language-service": "~11.1.0",
 "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
 "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
 "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
 "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
 "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
 "karma": "~5.2.3",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
 "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
 "protractor": "~7.0.0",
 "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
 "tslint": "~6.1.0",
 "typescript": "~4.0.5"
}
}
```

Comment: Add the error log to the post.

Comment: Ok, I am adding the logs. Thanks for the suggestion. @hbamithkumara

Comment: corresponding log added @hbamithkumara

Answer (score 0):

It seems some of the packages are not installed. You need to install packages then try running the app.

Try the following steps.

- Go to project directory
- Remove npm_modules directory
- Clean npm cache `npm cache clean --force`
- Verify cache `npm cache verify`
- Install dependencies `npm install`
- Run the app `npm start` or `ng serve`

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I have added this part to my post. "If I delete the node modules and reinstall the packages it works, but every time doing this is really a wastage of time."
I have to reinstall it every time I start my pc, do you know any way around to get rid of this problem?

Comment: You do it once. doing the cache clean might help. And try to reproduce the issue then.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening probably because you are using an updated version of node. Try downgrading your node version to `12.11.x or later minor version`.

Ref: https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Comment: After downgrading the node version it works for the first time, but whenever I restart my pc it says the node_modules folder is corrupted. Also, npm start throws the same error. My pc configuration is given below `Processor AMD Ryzen 5 2400G with Radeon Vega Graphics 3.60 GHz Installed RAM 32.0 GB (29.9 GB usable) System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor Edition Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2 Installed on ‎18/‎03/‎2021 OS build 19042.867` Does the os or my amd processor occur this issues?? @sifat moonjerin

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a problem with node or npm or angular,

- Problem occurs when the node was installed in my SSD but my project
  was in my HDD, after taking my project to SSD it solved the error,
  Now every time I do not need to reinstall my packages by removing the
  node modules.